# Bibtex: cite-key instead of question mark if not found

Tags: bibtex, natbib, cite-package

Iintensive search has not yield any answer, but I still suspect this might be a double-post:

Instead of a question mark, I want to have the cite-key if the reference was not found in the bib file. Is there an easy package  / command for this?

So far, I'm using `natbib` and my bibliography style is `chicago` (if it matters).

/edit
In my header, I have

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
```

Comment: If the entry does not exist, or if BibTeX was not run, question marks would appear. Instead of those question marks, you want do have the bibkey? Did i understand this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` does this by default, and the `biblatex-chicago` package provides several different Chicago styles, see the manual. Note that the default backend for `biblatex` is `biber`, not `bibtex`, so the compilation sequence is

```
pdflatex file.tex
biber file.bcf
pdflatex file.tex
```

The bibkeys are also displayed before running `biber` and `pdflatex` the second time, whenever you'd get question marks with `natbib`/`bibtex`.

When switching from `natbib` to `biblatex-chicago` you need to make several changes in your document:

- Replace `\usepackage[round]{natbib} \bibliographystyle{chicago}` in the preamble with

  ```
  \usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
  \addbibresource{nameofyourbibfile.bib}
  ```
- Replace `\bibliography{nameofyourbibfile}` in your document with `\printbibliography`.
- Replace `\citet` with `\textcite` and `\citep` with `\parencite`. Use Find&replace in your editor to do this.

(Normally with plain `biblatex` you could have added `natbib=true` to the package options which would have made `\citet` and `\citep` available, but `biblatex-chicago` does not define this.)

Some questions with more information about `biblatex`:

- [What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091)
- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)
- [biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)
- [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/)

Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{aksin}

\textcite{notavailable}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to integrate this the way I'm calling chicago? (see edit). I'd be afraid unknown side effects depending on the way I call it..

Comment: @FooBar No, you can't. `biblatex` and `natbib` are completely different systems, and `\bibliographystyle` won't work with the former. I don't know exactly how that `bibliographystyle` looks, but `biblatex-chicago` should have implemented the style defined by the Chicago Manual of Style. I'll update my answer in a bit, with some more info.